# Deep select accociated model data Cakephp 2.x

Tags: php

i have this model structure   Client->Project->Landlord->Property

Property belongsto Landlord
Landlord  belongsto Project
Project belongsto Client

inside the properties controller i want all the properties that belong to a specific client
How do i do this i have tried it with containable but it always gives me all Properties and not the ones that are related with their foreign keys.

```
  $properties = $this->Property->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'Landlord' => array(
            'Project' => array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'client_id' => $user['client_id']   // Passed parameter
                )
            ),
            'conditions' => array(
                'Landlord.project_id' => 'Project.Id'
            )
        )
      )
 ));
```

This isn't doing anything, it evens seems to ignore any typo's i made. what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Oke i figured it out with joins this is what i came up with.

```
  $joins = array(
           array('table'=>'projects', 
                 'alias' => 'Project',
                 'type'=>'inner',
                 'conditions'=> array(
                 'Project.client_id = '.$user['client_id']
           )),
           array('table'=>'landlords', 
                 'alias' => 'Landlord',
                 'type'=>'inner',
                 'conditions'=> array(
                 'Project.id = Landlord.project_id','Landlord.id = Property.landlord_id'
           )),

         );

        $properties = $this->Property->find('all',array('joins'=>$joins,'recursive'=>-1));
```